# How to play an image slideshow in a windowed mode/non Fullscreen on Linux?

Tags: linux-mint, images, slideshow

I need to play an image slideshow on the side while I work in other window. How to do that?

Comment: What are you using? LibreOffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using imagemagick

```
animate -pause 2 *.jpg
```

[image]

Using feh

```
feh --quiet --geometry 640x480 --borderless --hide-pointer --randomize --slideshow-delay 30 --recursive .
```

From [man page](http://manpages.org/feh) - few thing you might find useful

```
-Z , --auto-zoom
Zoom pictures to screen size in fullscreen / fixed geometry mode.
-x , --borderless
Create borderless windows.
-P , --cache-thumbnails
Enable thumbnail caching in ~/.thumbnails Only works with thumbnails <= 256x256 pixels.
--cycle-once
Exit after one loop through the slideshow.
-d , --draw-filename
Draw the filename at the top-left of the image.
--draw-tinted
Show overlay texts (as created by --draw-filename et al ) on a semi-transparent background to improve their readability
-f , --filelist file
This option is similar to the playlists used by music software. If file exists, it will be read for a list of files to load, in the order they appear. The format is a list of image filenames, absolute or relative to the current directory, one filename per line.
If file doesn't exist, it will be created from the internal filelist at the end of a viewing session. This is best used to store the results of complex sorts (-Spixels for example ) for later viewing.

Any changes to the internal filelist (such as deleting a file or it being pruned for being unloadable) will be saved to file when exits. You can add files to filelists by specifying them on the command line when also specifying the list.

If file is Qq - , will read the filelist from its standard input.
-F , --fullscreen
Make the window fullscreen. Note that in this mode, large images will always be scaled down to fit the screen, --zoom zoom only affects smaller images and never scales larger than necessary to fit the screen size. The only exception is a zoom of 100, in which case images will always be shown at 100% zoom, no matter their dimensions.
-g , --geometry [width x height [+ x + y ] ]
Limit (and don't change) the window size. Takes an X-style geometry string like 640x480 with optional +x+y window offset. Note that larger images will be zoomed out to fit, but you can see them at 1:1 by clicking the zoom button. Also note that this option does not enforce the geometry, changing it by a tiling WM or manually is still possible. After each resize, the resulting window size is used as the new size limit.
-Y , --hide-pointer
Hide the pointer (useful for slideshows)
-B , --image-bg style
Use style as background for transparent image parts and the like. Accepted values: checks, white, black. The default for windowed mode is checks, while fullscreen defaults to black.
--keep-zoom-vp
When switching images, keep zoom and viewport settings (zoom level and X, Y offsets)
--max-dimension width x height
Only show images with width <= width and height <= height If you only care about one parameter, set the other to 0 (or a negative value)
--min-dimension width x height
Only show images with width >= width and height >= height If you only care about one parameter, set the other to 0.
--no-screen-clip
By default, window sizes are limited to the screen size. With this option, windows will have the size of the image inside them. Note that they may become very large this way, making them unmanageable in certain window managers.
-n , --reverse
Reverse the sort order. Use this to invert the order of the filelist. E.g. to sort in reverse width order, use -nSwidth
-. , --scale-down
Scale images to fit window geometry (defaults to screen size when no geometry was specified). Note that the window geometry is not updated when changing images at the moment. This behaviour may change in the future. This option is ignored when in fullscreen mode.
In tiling environments, this also causes the image to be centered in the window
```

[image]

mplayer

```
mplayer mf://*.jpg -mf fps=10
```

impressive

```
impressive -XQa3 *
```

eog

```
eog --slide-show ./
```

Comment: i tried animate. But it isnt delaying the play. It quickly plays all of them even when pause is 60

Comment: @kramer try feh : feh --quiet --geometry 640x480 --slideshow-delay 60 --recursive .

Comment: @kramer feel free to accept the answer and upvote it if it helped